# Auto-Refresh RSS Feed in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, refresh-rate, refresh

I added an XML source using the Developer tab on Excel to load an RSS feed onto Excel. I wanted to make Excel automatically refresh the feed every 30 seconds, however, when I go to the Data tab to change the refresh settings, the Refresh Control/background refresh/auto-refresh boxes are grayed out.

There have been a few posts asking how to enable auto-refresh (from the data tab) when it is grayed out (as seen in picture), but none of the solutions have worked for me. I've also searched on many different sites how to enable it, but I am still unable to figure it out. Many sites tell you to make sure a cell with data is selected before going into refresh settings, but that hasn't worked either.

Does anyone have any solutions to fix this? Or, can anyone suggest a VBA script? I have no knowledge of programming, but if anyone has a VBA script, I'd appreciate it if you could write it out so that I may copy it onto the document. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/update-excel-worksheet-periodically-vba-timer/ https://support.office.com/en-us/article/refresh-connected-imported-data-e76a38b0-e2e1-400b-9f2f-c87b9b18c092

Comment: @STTR Thanks for the reply. I was following the Microsoft link and had this problem, which is what I wanted to ask. Sorry if it was unclear. I just tried the first link (datanumen) but it doesn't work for some reason either. I just get the loading symbol, but it doesn't update.

Comment: powershell ([xml](iwr "https://<rss feed site>/")).rss.channel.item^|Select Name,title,InnerText Test rss at cmd, maybe resource not response.

Comment: @STTR Hey, sorry I have absolutely no idea how to program or anything, do you mind elaborating on what this means? Thanks!

Comment: First I would like to know if your RSS works via any client application or browser, or via the command line. The command line in case of an emergency, if you suddenly have nothing to watch RSS feed without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Excel, infinity cycle and timer]

```
Sub TaskRefreash()
  Call RefreshData
End Sub

Sub RefreshData()
' Refresh all data source
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
' 30 min interval, set time interval in TimeValue
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "TaskRefreash"
End Sub
```

[image: Autorun code after open Workbook]
If neef autorun refresh data cycle after open Workbook, add: `Call TaskRefreash`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Call TaskRefreash
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your patience and answer! This worked. However, now the Excel document is extremely laggy. I don't think it's because of my computer being slow (I have a decent computer). Not sure if the lag can be fixed, but thanks again!